# Passing vector by value

Tags: c++

I want to create a program that uses a **vector** to sort it for testing reasons. So I want to calculate the CPU time by a benchmark that sorts the vector a certain amount of times. So the original vector needs to remain constant, and then use another vector so that it can be sorted.

So what I have done is...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> intv;

 int main(){
 intv vi;
 // Stuff to create my vector with certain characteristics...
 intv vii=vi;
 cout << "Size: \n";
 cin >> tt ;

 for(i=0; i<tt; ++i){
    tb=sort(t,vii);
    m=m+tb;
    vii=vi;
    }
  m=m/tt;
  cout << "BS" << m << "\n";

  }
```

So I pass the vector by reference, and make a copy for each sorting so that I can sort it again. How can I do this a better way? Is it better to pass it by value, and in that case, Could someone provide me a minimum example of the best way to do this?

**sort** is a basic bubble sorting function:

```
double sort(int t, intv &vii){
vii.reserve(t);
bool swapped=true;
int a;
auto t0 =chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
while (swapped==true){
        for (int i=1; i<t; ++i){
                swapped=false;
                if (vii[i-1]>vii[i]){
                        a=vii[i];
                        vii[i]=vii[i-1];
                        vii[i-1]=a;
                swapped=true;
                }
        }
        t=t-1;
}
auto t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
double T = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(t1-t0).count();
return T;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo from copying fractions of code.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using the STL sort algorithm?

Comment: For testing purposes. Indeed, I am not only using that sorting algorithm.

Comment: `t` is not declared in `tb=sort(t,vii);`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have sorted, you have to do something that is equivalent to:

```
vii=vi;
```

I think assigning `vi` to `vii` will be the most efficient method of copying the contents of `vi` to `vii`. You can try:

```
size_t index = 0;
for ( auto const& val : vi )
{
   vii[index++] = val;
}
```

However, I will be really surprised if the second method is more efficient than the first.

Comment: But using `vii=vi;` is not working, it is neither working `vector<vector<int> > vii(vi);
`

Comment: @D1X to get help with something "not working", post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with sorting in-place, and making a copy of the vector. The code you have should work, though it is not clear from where your parameter `t` is coming.

Note that the statement `vii.reserve(t)` is not doing anything useful in your sort routine: either `t` is less than or equal to the size of `vii`, in which case the reserve call does nothing, or it is greater than the size of `vii`, in which case you are accessing values outside the range of the vector. Better to check `t` against the vector size and throw an error or similar if it is too big.

Passing by value is straightforward: just declare your sort routine as `double sort(int t, intv vii)`. When the function is called, `vii` will be copied from whichever vector you pass in as the second argument.

From a design point of view though, it is better to make a copy and then pass a reference. Sorting *should* change the thing being sorted; passing by value in the context of your code would mean that nothing would be able to inspect the sorted result.